# describe protocol format in struct

Tags: c, struct

I would like to directly assign a `byte array` to a struct in C. The protocol looks like this(yes I know this is not compiling because flexlible arrays are only allowed as the last element of a struct)

```
struct telegram{
    uint8_t controll;
    uint16_t src_addr;
    uint16_t dst_addr;
    uint8_t is_group_addr :1;
    uint8_t routing_cnt :3;
    uint8_t data_len :3;
    uint8_t data[];
    uint8_t chksum;
};
```

how could I solve that? I like that I can directly access the field within the protocol very easy with a struct. The easy way would be to to say the last element of the `data[]` is the checksum, but I would like to know if there is a better/prettier way to do that.

Comment: Various aspects of layout are not guaranteed to be the same on different platforms; if you want this to work between different systems you’ll need to be more careful with layout. For example, if you didn’t intend to leave a completely unused and inaccessible byte between `controll` and `src_addr`, you should look into [GCC’s `packed` attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Type-Attributes.html#index-packed-type-attribute) and equivalent for other compilers. I’m not sure of any way to make the bit fields consistent, but there might be.

Comment: @DanielH thanks for the hint, didn't take padding in account yet!

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as your actual question goes I have no idea and don’t think it’s possible. There’s no way for the compiler to know, at compile time, what the offset of the checksum would be. Would it be reasonable to calculate/verify that during conversion to/from the array of bytes, and not include it in the struct?

Comment: Notice that using `packed` you will open a can of worms... better stay away from it; just read the packet in as a byte buffer, and decode the few header fields into a struct - you do not need to copy the `data`...

Comment: If you go with assumptions, at least add some static assertions on the struct size, so it won't let you compile in case your assumption is wrong.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala You’d still need testing, but `packed` is perfectly fine if you handle endianness and only use fixed-size types like this, at least without bitfields. I *think* it’s fine even with bitfields, but I’ve never used it there and am not sure.

Comment: ... and if you never take pointers to members, and do not address the members as volatile, and ...